# bitwise anding unsigned long with 0xffffffff

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

Below is some code from switch statement. `getvalue()` returns an `unsigned long`.
Could somebody explain why `value` is bitwise anded with `0xffffffff`. 
The mcu is 32 bit.

```
#define WriteMemory(A,V) *(volatile unsigned long*)(A)=(V)
static unsigned value;

case 'b':
value = getvalue();
value &= 0xffffffff;
WriteMemory(2147455555, value);
break;
```

Comment: No, nobody can explain that unless you post the variable declaration of `value`.

Comment: What does the assembler code show for optimised compilation on a typical 32 bit arch (ILP32) and a POSIX 64 bit arch (I32LP64)? What do you understand from that?

Comment: @Lundin I've update the question. `value` is declared as `static unsigned`. thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`unsigned long` isn't guaranteed to be 32 bit by the C standard. It is only guaranteed to be able to hold 32 bit values.

and-ing it with `0xffffffff` makes sure any bits over the 32 are zeroed out.

Answer (score 0):

The code uses what's sometimes called "naive/sloppy typing", meaning that it uses the basic `int` and `long` types from standard C. Those types are problematic and often non-portable, as they have implementation-defined size.

Because of the implementation-defined size, they pedantically mask out the lower 32 bits, in case `int` would for some reason turn up as 64 bits on some exotic system.

However, professional programs always use types of known size and signedness from `stdint.h`. This is particularly true for professional embedded systems.

The same code could be rewritten in much safer and portable ways as:

```
#include <stdint.h>

#define WriteMemory(A,V) ( *(volatile uint32_t*)(A)=(V) )
static uint32_t value;

case 'b':
value = getvalue();
WriteMemory(2147455555, value);
break;
```

`uint32_t` solves all problems: there's no longer any doubt how big the various types are, so it would be completely superfluous to mask with the lower 32 bits. Nor do you have to worry about implicit type promotions, given that this is a 32 bit system.

(Note the extra parenthesis in the macro, which is necessary to avoid classic macro operator precedence bugs such as `x = WriteMemory(2147455555, value) + y;` Bug: writes `value+y` which was probably not intended.)

Another much bigger concern here though, is if the given system will allow a misaligned 32 bit write at address 2147455555. Looks very fishy.